# GoogleMusic like Drawer to open an already opened activity from another activity?

Tags: android

Here is what i have done:Activity A launches Activity B which plays music from a service(all setup)
now i press back button
activity A appears. Now in activity A i want a drawer (i have setted a drawer before so setting up a drawer won't be a problem)
but now i want Activity B to be displayed when the drawer is drawn.....And i need help doing this.I don't need the code,just a way to do it..where should i begin?........
...................
.............
.....................................
..................

Comment: Why you are not using `Fragment`'s instead of `Activities` ?

Comment: The thing is ,actually Activity A is not an activity, its a fragment.. I setted  it up inside view pager.There are 3 fragments setup using a view pager to display them side by side.One of the fragment displays the song list(and not the activity ),the other is  artist-generating artist list and album.Clicking on any song plays the song in a new activity(Activity B) which itself has its swipe gestures.So if i create this new activity as a fragment along with those 3 fragments,i will loose the functionality of those swipe gestures. that's why.....

Comment: @Android-Developer  ...........?